# How to check if entered ID is unique with C

Tags: c

I am trying to develop a Customer Orders System using C. As the user chooses the option to add a customer, the system asks the user to enter Customer ID. I need a function that checks whether the entered ID already exists in the Customers File. Any help please?

Comment: I'd start by writing said-function and see how well it works.

Comment: Well you need to write the function to check if the entered id exists in the Customers file. Check how to open a file and read it contents line by line and compare it on each iteration. A well designed application will usually use a database as persistent storage to store customers and checking if entry exists will be as simple as calling an sql query.

Comment: what are your problems? what have you tried so far? how well it went? what problems have you encountered? you've not posted an actual question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for concrete technical questions for which the answer(s) might be of value to others, not only for you, and it is certainly not a site to do your home work for you. So please reformulate your question such that it points to a real technical problem, search the web an SO if you find an answer for that, and if not feel free to expose it here.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file and within a loop go on to compare each Customer ID with your entered one.

If it exists... break the loop, come out and display whatever error/message you wish to.

If it doesn't exist, silently accept it and proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a balanced binary tree and check if node was previously inserted, under linux you can make use of `<search.h>` (man tsearch), there is also a cross-platform library called libavl, it comes in a single .h: http://adtinfo.org/